# What are the drawbacks of not registering device using Hockeyapp?

Tags: hockeyapp

I notice that when our users receive the automated invite from HockeyApp to install a new corporate app we've provisioned for them, they first create a HockeyApp account and afterwards, they have an option to "Register Device" (which also requires installing the HockeyApp) or skip.  I want the user to have the fewest steps possible so I'm leaning toward having them skip the device registration.  Anyone know what I'll miss out on if I have the users to opt-out of registering their device?

Comment: Is this for iOS or Android?

Comment: @LukasSpieß for both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For iOS, the benefit of having users register their devices is that it allows you to easily export their devices' UDIDs and add those to your provisioning profiles, see https://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/client-integration-ios-mac-os-x-tvos/adding-new-ios-devices-to-your-provisioning-profile

For further info about the differences between different options HockeyApp offers for how to invite iOS beta testers, I recommend this knowledge base article: https://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/app-management-2/how-to-invite-beta-testers#no-account-existing-group-of-testers

On Android, the benefits are not as big because there is no real need to know your users' device details but if they register them, you will still get the ability to export a CSV file with all your users devices, OEMs, models, etc. should you be interested in those kinds of statistics.